# RSS from the whole Sharepoint portal

Tags: rss, aggregation

It would be nice to have an RSS feed from the whole Sharepoint portal, all lists, webs which a current user has access to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way out of the box to aggregate all the RSS feeds in SharePoint into one feed.  You would either have to build something, or you might consider looking at something like Yahoo Pipes (http://pipes.yahoo.com).  Even with something like Yahoo Pipes you would have to add all the feeds manually into it's data stream.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution

http://red1s.wordpress.com/2009/12/02/enabling-rss-feeds-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Thank you. But the question is how to aggregate multiple rss feeds.